# Colorizing text in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, colors, turbo-c++

How can I write colored text in **Turbo C++**? That is, how can I write different text with different colors and also have different Background colors?

For example like this...

```
textcolor(2); 
cprintf("\n\t Hello World");
```

But I want to set a background color for the "Hello World" text, also.

[image: CLICK Too See Image..]

Comment: Actually time machine does exist. The last time I used turbo c++ 26 years ago.

Comment: Sweet memories! I think I still have those two floppies somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use of `textbackground` function for coloring background of text and use of `textcolor` function for coloring the text.

before using of these functions, include `<stdio.h>` header file!

for coloring every text variously, you must first set `textbackground` and `textcolor` for each other, then use of `cprintf` function.

**Attention bellow example:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    //full screen window w: 80, h: 50
    window(1,1,80,50);
    textbackground(0);//black color
    clrscr();
    textcolor(15); //white color
    gotoxy(1,1); cprintf("WINDOW-1");

    //window 2
    window(10,10,40,20);
    textbackground(1); //blue color
    clrscr();
    textcolor(15); //white color
    gotoxy(1,1); cprintf("WINDOW-2");
    //pause screen
    getch();
}
```