# ANSI Color Specific RGB Sequence Bash

Tags: ansi-escape

I know that in bash terminals a reliable way to change color is using ANSI escape sequences. For example:

```
echo -e "\033[0;31mbrown text\033[0;00m"
```

should output

```
brown text (in brown)
```

Is there a way to output color using a specific RGB set with ANSI? Say I want bright red:

```
echo -e "**\033[255:0:0m**red text\033[0;00m"
```

Does this sort of thing exist?

I just want to use standard bash.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good article on [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics)! But, though they say there's a way to generate RGB colored output (`\033[38;2;r;g;bm`), I can't seem to make it work in my gnome-terminal.

Comment: Worth mentioning: this has nothing to do with `bash`. ANSI escape sequences are interpreted by your *terminal* (`gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, `konsole`, etc). `bash` is just a *shell* (command interpreter) launched by your terminal.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This does exist, but instead of the 16777216 (256^3) colors that the OP was looking for, there are 216 (6^3) equally distributed colors, in a larger set of 256 colors. Example:

```
echo -e "\033[38;5;208mpeach\033[0;00m"
```

This will output a pleasing sort of peach colored text.

---

Taking apart this command: **\033[38;5;208m**

The **\033** is the escape code. The **[38;** directs command to the **foreground**. If you want to change the background color instead, use **[48;** instead. The **5;** is just a piece of the sequence that changes color. And the most important part, **208m**, selects the actual  color.

---

There are 3 sets of colors that can be found in the 256 color sequence for this escape. The first set is the basic "candy" color set, or values 0-15. Then there is a cube of distributed colors, from 16-231. Lastly there is a detailed grayscale set from 232-255.

You can find a table with all of these values here: [http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux#256%20(8-bit)%20Colors](http://web.archive.org/web/20131009193526/http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux)

Comment: @AaronJLang `\e` is not supported in all shells.

Comment: 0–256 is not 256 colors; it's 257 colors! :P

Comment: @HelloGoodbye it's actually.. 0-255 (255 is the max) so their 256 was already correct..

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Just posted my [HSV - RGB browser bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905494/1765658)

Comment: Quick little bash one-liner that will show all the colors: `for x in {0..255}; do echo -e "\033[38;5;${x}mColor $x\033[0;0m"; done`

Comment: Just so you guys know, TERM and COLORTERM (and termcap,etc) are only used to help programs determine the terminal they are on. Many modern terminals will support color codes regardless of these settings.  For example, modern day uxterm will always support RGB and 256-color codes. You would do well to read into the manpage for xterm to find out under which circumstances it will be supported. TERM is mainly a fallback for when you don't want to guess, and usually results in 256 colors even though 16m is actually supported!  The moral is not to rely fully on termcap for colors on modern terminals

Answer (score 106):

Both answers here fail to mention the [Truecolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#True_color_.2824-bit.29) [ANSI support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) for 8bpc color. This will get the RGB color the OP originally asked for.

Instead of `;5`, use `;2`, and specify the *R*, *G*, and *B* values (0-255) in the following three control segments.

```
\x1b[38;2;40;177;249m
```

To test [if your terminal supports Truecolor](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#now-supporting-truecolor):

```
printf "\x1b[38;2;40;177;249mTRUECOLOR\x1b[0m\n"
```

On my machine, XTerm happily outputted the correct color; although, terminals that are modeled after terminals that predate modern RGB color generally will not support truecolor - make sure you know your target before using this particular variant of the escape code.

---

I'd also like to point out the `38` and the `;5`/`;2` - Blue Ice [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712766/510036) that `38` routes and then `5` changes the color. That is slightly incorrect.

`38` is the xterm-256 extended foreground color code; `30`-`37` are simply 16-color foreground codes (with a brightness controlled by escape code `1` on some systems and the arguably-supported `90`-`97` non-standard 'bright' codes) that are supported by all vt100/xterm-compliant colored terminals.

The `;2` and `;5` indicate the format of the color, ultimately telling the terminal how many more sequences to pull: `;5` specifying an 8-bit format (as Blue Ice mentioned) requiring only 1 more control segment, and `;2` specifying a full 24-bit RGB format requiring 3 control segments.

These extended modes are *technically* "undocumented" and are completely implementation defined. As far as I know and can research, they are *not* governed by the ANSI committee.

---

For the so inclined, the `5;` (256 color) format starts with the 16 original colors (both dark/light, so 30-37 and 90-97) as colors 0-15.

The proceeding 216 colors (16-231) are formed by a 3bpc RGB value offset by 16, packed into a single value.

The final 24 colors (232-256) are greyscale starting from a shade slightly lighter than black ranging up to a shade slightly darker than white. Some emulators interpret these steps as linear increments from (`256 / 24`) on all three channels, though I've come across some emulators that seem to explicitly define these values.

Here is a Javascript function that performs such a conversion, taking into account all of the greys.

```
function rgbToAnsi256(r, g, b) {
    // we use the extended greyscale palette here, with the exception of
    // black and white. normal palette only has 4 greyscale shades.
    if (r === g && g === b) {
        if (r < 8) {
            return 16;
        }

        if (r > 248) {
            return 231;
        }

        return Math.round(((r - 8) / 247) * 24) + 232;
    }

    var ansi = 16
        + (36 * Math.round(r / 255 * 5))
        + (6 * Math.round(g / 255 * 5))
        + Math.round(b / 255 * 5);

    return ansi;
}
```

So in a way, you can [calculate](https://github.com/Qix-/color-convert/blob/427cbb70540bb9e5b3e94aa3bb9f97957ee5fbc0/conversions.js#L555-L580) 256 ANSI colors from initial RGB values by reducing them from 8 to 3 bits in order to form a 256 encoded value in the event you want to programmatically do so on terminals that do not support Truecolor.

Comment: For posterity, I am the maintainer of the repository linked at the bottom of this post.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot in Python.

Comment: This helped me to modify colors in some asciicasts created using [asciinema](https://asciinema.org). I needed to use `\u001b` to start the escape sequence instead of `\x1b`.

Answer (score 7):

This will work

```
echo -e "**\033[38;2;255;0;0m**red text\033[0;00m"
```

format: `"\033[38;2;R;G;Bm"`

- R is your RED component of your RGB
- G is your GREEN component of your RGB
- B is your BLUE component of your RGB

Answer (score 3):

Currently true color escape sequences (\e[38;2;R;G;Bm) are supported by certain terminal emulators including gnome-terminal (with vte >= 0.36), konsole, and st [suckless].

The feature is *not* supported by certain others, e.g. pterm [putty], terminology [enlightenment], urxvt.

xterm is halfway in between: it recognizes the escape sequences, but rounds every color to the nearest one in the 256-color palette.

Comment: Interesting factoid about Xterm. They're apparently doing it wrong, too.

Answer (score 3):

## Playing with RGB (and HSV) in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

### ANSI sequences in *terminal*.

There are two way of printing colors in bash.

After playing with nice tools found on [xterm's source tree](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/tree/master/vttests), here is how `vttests/256colors2.pl` show on my *gnome-terminal*:

[image: vttests/256colors2.pl]

show `256` colors:  `16` *terminal colors* + `6 * 6 * 6` *RGB levels* + `24` grayscales.

this use ANSI syntax `\e[48;5;COLORm`:

```
printf '\e[48;5;%sm' $color;
```

instead of `\e[48;2;RED;GREEN;BLUEm`:

```
printf '\e[48;2;%s;%s;%sm' $red $green $blue;
```

I've done some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) functions to play with RGB, and HSV:

#### RGB to HSV

```
hsv() {
    local -n _result=$4
    local -i _hsv_min _hsv_t
    local _hsv_s
    local -i _hsv_max=" $1 > $2 ?
                (_hsv_min=($2 > $3 ? $3:$2 ), ( $1 > $3 ? $1 : $3 )) :
                (_hsv_min=($1 > $3 ? $3:$1 ), $2) > $3 ? $2 : $3 "
    case $_hsv_max in 
        $_hsv_min) _hsv_t=0 ;;
        $1) _hsv_t=" ( 60 * ( $2 - $3 ) / ( _hsv_max-_hsv_min )+ 360 )%360";;
        $2) _hsv_t=" 60 * ( $3 - $1 ) / ( _hsv_max-_hsv_min )+ 120 " ;;
        $3) _hsv_t=" 60 * ( $1 - $2 ) / ( _hsv_max-_hsv_min )+ 240 " ;;
    esac
    _hsv_s=0000000$(( _hsv_max==0?0 : 100000000-100000000*_hsv_min / _hsv_max ))
    printf -v _hsv_s %.7f ${_hsv_s::-8}.${_hsv_s: -8}
    _result=($_hsv_t $_hsv_s $_hsv_max)
}
```

Then

```
RED=255 GREEN=240 BLUE=128
hsv $RED $GREEN $BLUE hsvAr
echo ${hsvAr[@]}
52 0.4980392 255
printf 'Hue: %d, Saturation: %f, Value: %d\n' "${hsvAr[@]}"
Hue: 52, Saturation: 0.498039, Value: 255
```

#### HSV to RGB

```
rgb() {
    local -n _result=$4
    local -i _rgb_i=" (($1%360)/60)%6 "
    local -i _rgb_f=" 100000000*($1%360)/60-_rgb_i*100000000 "
    local _rgb_s
    printf -v _rgb_s %.8f "$2"
    _rgb_s=$((10#${_rgb_s/.}))
    local -i _rgb_l=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_s)/100000000 "
    case $_rgb_i in
        0 )
            local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$3" "$_rgb_n" "$_rgb_l") ;;
        1 )
            local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_m" "$3" "$_rgb_l") ;;
        2 )
            local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_l" "$3" "$_rgb_n") ;;
        3 )
            local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_l" "$_rgb_m" "$3") ;;
        4 )
            local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_n" "$_rgb_l" "$3") ;;
        * )
            local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$3" "$_rgb_l" "$_rgb_m") ;;
    esac
}
```

Then

```
rgb 160 .6 240 out
echo ${out[@]}
96 240 192
printf '\e[48;5;%d;%d;%dm    \e[0m\n' "${out[@]}"
```

Will produce a bunch of colored spaces.

#### Further: [hsvrgb-browser.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb-browser.sh.txt)

**Preamble:** Store previous two function into a file called [`hsvrgb.sh`](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb.sh.txt), stored in **same** directory than downloaded [hsvrgb-browser.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/hsvrgb-browser.sh.txt).

[image]

```
HSV-RGB Color browser - Usage: 

  [RrGgBbVb] Incrase/decrase value by step ('1'), from 0 to 255..
  [HhTt]     Incrase/decrase Hue (tint), loop over 0 - 359.
  [Ss]       Increase/decrase Saturation by .006 x step (1).
  [Cc]       Toggle Color bar rendering (upper C fix HSV)
  [+-]       Incrase/decrase step.
  [u]        show this.
  [q]        quit.
```

**Note:** Regarding [mmeisner' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086928/mmeisner), If you encounter issue with this script, try to run them by:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF8 ./hsvrgb-browser.sh
```

**Important note:** Ensure your terminal support 256colors! (Don't blame this if run under `screen`, `tmux` or any 16 color terminal!)

Comment: I get some beautiful grey scales but lots of errors about `printf` in `hsvrgb.sh` and then the script exits with `/hsvrgb-browser.sh: line 78: 1669805727,097315: value too great for base (error token is "097315")`

Comment: @mmeisner Seem to be a problem with locales. Try to run this by: `LC_ALL=C.UTF8 ./hsvrgb-browser.sh`

Comment: Absolutely perfect! The locale trick did it. I love this script. Well done!

Comment: I added `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` to the top of the script. That also works. For some reason `export LC_ALL=C.UTF8` (no dash) does not work from inside the script, only on the command-line. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

No there's not.

And to nitpick, those are technically not "ANSI escape sequences" but [VT100 control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) (which were defined long before there were graphical terminals and terms like "RGB").

Comment: Yes, [there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), though it's not supported by many shells. Instead of `38;5`, you would use `38;2`. Just tried it in XTerm - works fine.

Comment: @Qix You can set colors, but I'm answering the question if one can set *RGB colors*, i.e. arbitrary colors, which is not possible.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting your information, but yes; look at my answer. Full 24-bit RGB colors.

Comment: @Qix There seems to be some conflicting information about the [ISO-8613-3](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=22939) standard, as it's about [Open Document Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Document_Architecture) and not any VT100-like coloring codes. Also, it seems that the coloring-codes is very new, and limited to few terminal emulators.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: by *"very new"* you mean more than a *decade*? And by *"limited to a few terminals"* you mean the default X terminals from Gnome and KDE, and also XTerm and the Linux Console?

Comment: I find it a little funny that the link you posted has the title "ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences."