# How to change the color of text to ANY color in C++

Tags: c++

So I need to change the color of text to, **pink** as the foreground and black as the background. I've searched google but I can't find any thing that says how to change the text color to pink (or any other colors aside from blue/red/green etc.). I know about

```
system("Color *back**fore*")
```

But that doesn't have pink. So can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: That depends on your terminal.

Comment: What OS or are you,looking for something protable?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences/4842438#4842438

Comment: What about `ncurses`?

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for linux based terminals.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){

  char pinkish[] = { 0x1b, '[', '3', '8',';','5',';','2','1','2','m',0 };
  char normal[] = { 0x1b, '[', '0', ';', '3', '9', 'm', 0 };

  cout << pinkish << "Hello" << normal << endl;

}
```

Using the ANSI Color Codes, scroll down to the 256 bit color table.

```
{ 0x1b, '[', '3', '8',';','5',';','2','1','2','m',0 };
```

FOREGROUND COLOR: ESC[38;5;

BACKGROUND COLOR: ESC[48;5;

256 bit color value: 212

terminal character (I'm guessing): m

Hope this helps, it was interesting to research it. There is lot's of good info out there - way lots, but hopefully I summarized down to just what you asked for.

A couple of references:

[Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux](http://web.archive.org/web/20131009193526/http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Using-ANSI-Color-Codes-to-Colorize-Your-Bash-Prompt-on-Linux)

[ansi-color-specific-rgb-sequence-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682537/ansi-color-specific-rgb-sequence-bash)

[color for text](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1640/)