# Is there a way to display different characters in different colors in a C++ program in VS code's integrated terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, animation, themes, background-color

I am currently working on a project that requires me to display various characters in different colors, but I have no idea how to go about it. Also could it be possible to add slight animations to the code that I make ,that execute in the runtime, if so, then please tell me how it can be done.

For example if I want to display:
A B C D E F
I want all of them to have a different colour

I tired changing the background and foreground color at various points in the whole code but ,even if it changed the color it changed all of them to the same color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the ANSI Escape code for outputting colored text on Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414983/how-to-use-the-ansi-escape-code-for-outputting-colored-text-on-console) In particular, see [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026809/11107541) that I just wrote.