# How do i clear the VS CODE terminal mid execution with a command/function?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, terminal

Kinda new to programming.
I found my self with this problem while programming a
tic tac toe like game in C++ but since it keeps printing the game table it quickly becomes a mess to read and understand.

Is there a way to clear the terminal with a command or function to put inside the code so it clears itself automatically?

I tried to mess with the settings but it just clear the terminal after the end of the code,
I also tried to find an already done function/instruction in vs code but with no luck.
I will be more then happy with just an external function in json.

Comment: There's a button for that in the UI, I believe. If you want to do it programmatically, it's going to be OS-specific, which one are you using?

Comment: I have no idea how VSCode terminal works, I suppose it's more like a Powershell console. There's tiny chance that it recognizes good ol' escape codes - try "\033[2J" where \033 is the character having code "escape", 033 oct, 0x1B hex, etc - https://espterm.github.io/docs/VT100%20escape%20codes.html + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code + https://duffney.io/usingansiescapesequencespowershell/ - edit: I just tried in several "consoles" I have - it printed out the control characters, so I suppose my terminals do not support control sequences :D Same in my VSCode. Wrong way then!

Answer (score 0):

VSCode terminal is a powershell console. Search for things like 'powershell command for xxx' with this in mind.

Quick search pointed me to `Clear-Host` command.

I tried that in VSCode terminal, and yea, it cleared the screen.
You might want to read the whole article I found, as it tackles some additional issues regarding clearing the 'screen', you might need it for a clean 'game screen'.

src: https://kgk.gr/2011/10/16/powershell-clrscr/

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can use the `std::system()` function which executes a command into the terminal

---

you can execute the commands:

- `std::system("cls")` (*for Windows*)
- `std::system("clear")` (*for most Linux operating systems*)

---

this code **should** work also in Visual Studio code because it runs in the terminal in both.

[example of usage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's integrated terminal uses [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js), which supports most [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), including the ones for "Erase in Display". Ex. `CSI 2 J` or `CSI 3 J`. In C++, I think you could put that in a string literal like `std::cout << "\e[2J"` (and you probably want to flush the output right after printing that unless you're fine with it being buffered until the next automatic output buffer flush). If you want ANSI escape codes to work in a windows terminal outside of VS Code, you may or may not need to [enable console virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026809/11107541.