# Changed shell color, now have display errors

Tags: shell

I put in place color codes on our Centos7 servers with a file in /etc/profile.d/file.sh :

```
export PS1="\e[1;36m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

Thing is, now, when I go through my CLI history after typing in a command as root, it will not replace all of the command, which makes it hard to read.

Example :
I would type

```
sudo yum install php php-cli
```

Then type something else. Then if i want to go back in the history using the up arrow on my keyboard, I will end up having things like :

```
sudo yum ils-l
sudo yum ips aux |grep total
sudo yum icat /var/log/httpd
```

Instead of

```
ls -l
ps aux | grep total
cat /var/log/httpd
```

I assume the two are linked, but I can't manage to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Side note: There is no reason to `export` the `PS1` variable.

Comment: If the `<%= @color %>` in your PS1 is replaced by something else, you should post the resulting PS1 (e. g. from `set|grep PS1`), because only that matters. And are you using some other shell than `bash`?

Comment: Updated OP with correct PS1. Only using bash. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @color %>` is not a valid syntax for a color mode number; replace that by a number from 30 to 37; see [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences).

Comment: sorry, it's the chef notation. It actually is a number.

Comment: @Paul-antoine Kempf: I would not be so sure about that - if it actually were a number, the PS1 would be correct. See my comment to the question.