# Color text in discord

Tags: css, node.js, discord

My goal is to partly color a text. I know I can use `.sendCode("css","this is my message");` which we'll make my text yellow but I don't want my whole text to be yellow.

Perhaps I could create another .css file and then call it from my JavaScript file but as I am inexperienced with JavaScript I would like some help with it. I think that's the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**(Updated for 2022)**

In 2022's polish week, Discord added support for ansi on code blocks, previously it was not possible to display colors on the chat, however you could "mimic" colored output by selecting specific highlighted languages like `prolog` or `css`.

To display colored text using code-blocks, you simply need to create a code block with the language set to `ansi` and then use any of the [several ansi escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/4592841) to style your text.

Here is a simple example of a message which will display in red. The escape code used for ansi is `\033`.

````
```ansi
[0;31m RED TEXT
```
````

Do note however, that Discord does not render all colors as you would expect them, having some special issues with background colors being mostly shades of grey.

[image: ansi color preview on discord]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Fabricio20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992297/5113030), the current escape character Discord clients use is [U+001B](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/001B.html). For example:

```bash
[{ansiCode1};{ansiCode2};{ansiCode3}mTest # The general format (multiple codes supported)
[0;36;40mTest # Test (font color "Cyan", background color - "Black")
[0;35mTest # Test (font color "Magenta")
```

Note the very first character which may not be visible or represent relatively ambiguous visuals in certain circumstances (e.g. unsupported/custom font/charset). It may represent a rectangle:
[image: U+001B]

It seems Discord ANSI colors relatively differ if compared with some general color tables (e.g. the above test):

[image]

Submitted message:

[image: example]

Perhaps it's worth to mention that some try experimenting with an HTML (`&#x1B`) or Unicode (`\u001b`) encoded character reference instead of the actual "raw" ANSI character identification, though so far it's noticed that Discord processes messages with the latter only.

---

Related:
- [*Discord is now slowly rolling out the ability to send colored messages within*...](https://gist.github.com/kkrypt0nn/a02506f3712ff2d1c8ca7c9e0aed7c06)
- [*ANSI escape code - Wikipedia*...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)