# Formatting a border with printF

Tags: java, netbeans, printf

I've currently built a little project and I've started to learn about formatting outputs with printf? I haven't built a GUI, it's just a simple running program on netbeans and I'm hoping to get outputs like this

```
Username: *user input*
Age: *User Input *                     Company: *User Input*
Date: *Current Date*                   Grade: *User Input*
Job Type: *User Input*                 Discount: *Yes/No*
Town: *User Input*                 Phone Number: *User Input*
                 Total Price: *User Input*
```

I'm also looking to learn how to do a dash square border all around the outputs, I've seen a few online and they look very cool but I don't know how to do them.

Here is the format I am seeking with the inputs

[image: Here is the format I am seeking with the inputs]

Is there any possible way to make it look like this but with a border?

Answer (score 0):

if I was you I would use ANSI colors - you can change the background
color and more on your console output, and terminal with these

This will be printed in red :)

```
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "This text is red!" + ANSI_RESET);
```

[List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences)

For more options:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: That's cool as hell! Thank you for that I'll definitely be adding some colour schemes. But do you know how to position the text the way I want it positioning in my question? That's what I'm really struggling with at the moment, I can't seem to grasp it.

Comment: It donst always work as I would like it but in a String you can tab that will give you a nice seperation .... String str = "this is text, and this \t is at tab":) if you want I can write an example