# Print cmd with colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

I am trying to get colored command line output. I was able to get colored Python console output using `colorama` with this:

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style

print(f'{Fore.GREEN}A')
print(f'{Fore.RED}B')
print('C')
print(f'{Style.RESET_ALL}D')
print('E')
```

This perfectly works inside the Python Console in PyCharm. However, if I run the program under Windows `cmd`. There is no color at all but the colorama text is just added without any effect:

```
←[32mA
←[31mB
C
←[0mD
E
```

Can I modify the code so that it also works in Windows `cmd`?

Comment: Are you on some version below Windows 10?

Comment: @user69453: Yes, Win7.

Comment: Ok, because if you knew, you were on some version of Windows 10, you would not need `colorama`, since Windows 10 supports the ANSI escape sequences for colors, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/4408275).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add `convert=True` to your colorama init call:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style, init

init(convert=True)

print(f'{Fore.GREEN}A')
print(f'{Fore.RED}B')
print('C')
print(f'{Style.RESET_ALL}D')
print('E')
```

Comment: Thanks. That did indeed work. However, then it does not work in the Python Console any more... Is there a way to detect the environment and then convert or not depending?

Comment: You should be able to check `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).parent().name()`. Not sure what the values are for Windows, but it should be something like `"cmd"`.

Comment: Great! With that I was able to make it work! Thank you!

Comment: alternatively you can use `if "started_with_prompt" not in sys.argv:`

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Jeremiah I was able to make it work in PyCharm and cmd. Here is the complete code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
import psutil
import os

if psutil.Process(os.getpid()).parent().name() == 'cmd.exe':
    init(convert=True)

print(f'{Fore.GREEN}A')
print(f'{Fore.RED}B')
print('C')
print(f'{Style.RESET_ALL}D')
print('E')
```