# Sed replace regex with regex

Tags: bash, sed

Given the following `file.txt`:

```
this is line 1
# this is line 2
this is line 3
```

I would like to use sed to replace the lines with `#` at the beginning with `\e[31m${lineContent}\e[0m`. This will color that particular line. Additionally, I need the color `\e[31m` to be in a variable, `color`. (The desired output of this example would be having the second line colored). I have the following:

```
function colorLine() {
    cat file.txt | sed ''/"$1"/s//"$(printf \e[31m $1 \e[0m)"/g''
}
colorLine "#.*"
```

The variable `color` is not included in what I have so far, as I am not sure how to go about that part. 
The output of this is (with the second line being red):

```
this is line 1
#.*
this is line 3
```

It is apparently interpreting the replace string literally. My question is how do I use the matched line to generate the replace string?

I understand that I could do something much easier like appending `\e[31m` to the beginning of all lines that start with `#`, but it is important to use sed with the regexes.

Comment: The consecutive single quotes might as well not be there.  The first starts a single quoted string; the second stops it; neither is passed to the executed command.

Comment: This might help: [Using sed to color the output from a command on solaris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45924/74329)

Comment: Perhaps it's a quoting issue in the shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
colorLine() {
    sed "/$1/s//"$'\e[31m&\e[0m/' file.txt
}
colorLine "#.*"
```

Multiple fixes, but it uses `$1` to identify the pattern from the arguments to the function, and then uses [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to encode the escape sequences — and fixes the color reset sequence which was (originally) missing the `[` after the escape sequence.  It also avoids the charge of ["UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

The fixed file name is not exactly desirable, but fixing it is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

> What if I needed `\e[31m` to be a variable, `$color`. How do I change the quoting?

I have a `colour-diff` script which contains (in Perl notation — I've translated it to Bash notation using ANSI C quoting as before):

```
reset=$'\e[0m' 
black=$'\e[30;1m'      # 30 = Black,   1 = bold
red=$'\e[31;1m'        # 31 = Red,     1 = bold
green=$'\e[32;1m'      # 32 = Green,   1 = bold
yellow=$'\e[33;1m'     # 33 = Yellow,  1 = bold
blue=$'\e[34;1m'       # 34 = Blue,    1 = bold
magenta=$'\e[35;1m'    # 35 = Magenta, 1 = bold
cyan=$'\e[36;1m'       # 36 = Cyan,    1 = bold
white=$'\e[37;1m'      # 37 = White,   1 = bold
```

With those variables around, you can create your function as you wish:

```
colorLine() {
    sed "/$1/s//$blue&$reset/“ file.txt
}
```

Where you set those variables depends on where you define your function.  For myself, I'd probably make a script rather than a function, with full-scale argument parsing, and go from there.  [YMMV](https://www.acronymfinder.com/YMMV.html)

Take a look at [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences) to get a more comprehensive list of colours (and other effects — including background and foreground colours) and the escape sequence used to generate it.

Comment: This works. What if I needed `\e[31m` to be a variable, `$color`. How do I change the quoting?

Comment: It is so much easier if you ask the whole question all at once, rather than adding extras in dribs and drabs as answers come in.

Comment: Sorry, this was something I hadn't considered but now realize is somewhat important. I'll edit the question.

Comment: A small bug.  This `sed "/$1/s//$blue&$reset/'` should be `sed "/$1/s//$blue&$reset/2"`  (double quote at the final)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and Kubuntu 16.04.

```
foo="#.*"
sed 's/'"$foo"'/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd trick grep to do it for me this way:

```sh
function colorLine() {
    GREP_COLORS="mt=31" grep --color=always --context=$(wc -l <file.txt) --no-filename "$1" file.txt
}
```

Split-out of the trick:

- `GREP_COLORS="mt=31"`: SGR substring for matching non-empty text in any matching line. Here will generate `\e[31m` red before matched string, and reset to default color after matched string.
- `--color=always`: always colorise even in non interactive shell
- `context=$(wc -l <file.txt)`: output as much context lines as number of lines in the file (so all lines).
- `--no-filename`: do not print the file name

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
black='\033[30;1m'
red='\033[31;1m'
green='\033[32;1m'
yellow='\033[33;1m'
blue='\033[34;1m'
magenta='\033[35;1m'
cyan='\033[36;1m'
white='\033[37;1m'

color=$cyan
colorLine() { awk -v s="$1" -v c=$color '$0~s {$0=c$0"\033[0m"}1' file.txt; }
colorLine "#.*"
```

You can add file as a variable as vell:

```
color=$cyan
file="file.txt"
colorLine() { awk -v s="$1" -v c=$color '$0~s {$0=c$0"\033[0m"}1' $file; }
colorLine "#.*"
```

In `awk` `\e` is printed as `\033`

---

A more dynamic version:

```
colorLine() { 
    temp=$2;
    col=${!temp};
    awk -v s="$1" -v c=$col '$0~s {$0=c$0"\033[0m"}1' $3; }
colorLine "#.*" green file.txt
```

Then you have `colorLine pattern color file`