# Change Background on specific line in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

Trying to set the background for line 1 to white and line 2 to black. ASN1 Esc codes seems it would be the fastest way to get it. However it only changed the background at specified text not entire line.

Example of what I'm hoping for:

```
@echo off
echo <Esc>[107m This Entire line has a white background
echo <Esc>[40m This Entire Line has a black background
pause
```

what I am getting:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTFC4.png)

Comment: The color isn't applied by magic for the complete line, you need to force to print to the end of line by using spaces of better `<ESC>[K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jebs Comment is spot on.

Set the line position, invert the line, 'K' clear the line & then Position your text to save all that nasty spaces busines.

```
ECHO <ESC>[1;1H<ESC>[07m<ESC>[K<ESC>[1;55H Hello world
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and examples. Works wonders, still diving into ASN1 appreciate the boost!

Comment: It's quite useful, definitely an upgrade for Batch on the visual level.
This is a basic example of an Ansi Animation if your interested - https://pastebin.com/N8wQADXG

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

For extra tips on Stringing multiple ANSI codes together