# Git generated a file with a mysterious file name within visual studio code, what is this file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-log

I found this generated file named "d" in my directory, it looks like the history of a git log output for a particular branch, but it could be something different, this is an example of one of the lines of the file, modified.

```
[02m789c537890fac34567f6a784374c58d943[m Committing our changes
```

Does anyone have an idea of what this is, and how it gets generated?

Comment: Git didn't generate that file. It's something else in your toolchain.  If I knew what did generate it this'd be an answer not just a comment, but for sure it wasn't git.

Comment: Besides what @jthill said, the `[02m`...`[m` part looks like something trying to print in greyed-out (faint) text. The thing in between looks like a hash ID, but abbreviated to 34 bytes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/1256452

Comment: What *exactly* did you do before the file got generated? Why do you think git added it?

Comment: `Committing our changes` is the best commit message ever, it looks like a file that is a redirected output from some kind of program