# How can change color for some words in cmd?

Tags: terminal

I interest to what npm-cli do when installing package or run some script. There are some words with custom color. This is not for my project, i just want to know, how it works?

[image]

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

Comment: Thank you so much @HighPerformanceMark