# Convert to bold,italic,strikethrought text in java

Tags: java

how can I convert text to **bold**, *italic* & <s>strikethrough</s>? I've seen some tutorials which set the text in the window but that's not what I want. I want to base entirely on the console, no windows or anything like that.
Sample:

```
bold("ue") => 
italic("la") => 
strike("qw") => q̶w̶
```

> Thanks a lot! Your help is very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can style console text (text styles, colors) using **ANSI Escape Sequences**. Not every console may support it though. The top-voted answer in the following question provides an excellent overview on how to achieve this:

[List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences)