# printf data type specifier complex question

Tags: c++, c, printf

```
printf("\e[2J\e[0;0H");
```

What does this line mean?

Can I know what to learn and from where to understand this statement?

Comment: Looks like some terminal control codes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code This will offer some help.

Comment: Did you try just running it and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\e"` as an escape sequence is not part of the C standard.

A number of compilers treat the otherwise *undefined behavior* as a character with the value of 27 - the ASCII *escape* character.

Alternative well defined code:

```
//printf("\e[2J\e[0;0H");
printf("\x1B[2J\x1b[0;0H");
printf("\033[2J\033[0;0H");
#define ESC "\033"
printf(ESC "[2J" ESC "[0;0H");
```

The escape character introduces ANSI escape sequences as well answered in [@Mickael B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61734978/2410359).  Select terminals implement some of these sequences.

Answer (score 0):

They are [**ANSI escape sequences**](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

> These sequences define functions that change display graphics, control cursor movement, and reassign keys.

It starts with `\e[` and the following characters define what should happen.

#### `2J`: clears the terminal

> `Esc[2J`  **Erase Display**:
>   Clears the screen and moves the cursor to the home position (line 0, column 0).

#### `0;0H` moves the cursor to the position (0, 0)

> `Esc[Line;ColumnH`    **Cursor Position**:
>   Moves the cursor to the specified position (coordinates).

See also:

- [console_codes - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences)