# How to change font color to a specific line in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Surely there must be a way to add some color to the line in the code below where it shows m.codeletters = "&#*+%?£@§$"; etc? I want to change the color to : **"&#*+%?£@§$"**

```
var Messenger = function(el){
  'use strict';
  var m = this;
  
  m.init = function(){
    m.codeletters = "&#*+%?£@§$";
    m.message = 0;
    m.current_length = 0;
    m.fadeBuffer = false;
    m.messages = [
       'readers',
      'via feed',
      ''
    ];
    
    setTimeout(m.animateIn, 100);
  };
  
  m.generateRandomString = function(length){
    var random_text = '';
    while(random_text.length < length){
      random_text += m.codeletters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*m.codeletters.length));
    } 
    
    return random_text;
  };
  
  m.animateIn = function(){
    if(m.current_length < m.messages[m.message].length){
      m.current_length = m.current_length + 2;
      if(m.current_length > m.messages[m.message].length) {
        m.current_length = m.messages[m.message].length;
      }
      
      var message = m.generateRandomString(m.current_length);
      $(el).html(message);
      
      setTimeout(m.animateIn, 20);
    } else { 
      setTimeout(m.animateFadeBuffer, 20);
    }
  };
  
  m.animateFadeBuffer = function(){
    if(m.fadeBuffer === false){
      m.fadeBuffer = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < m.messages[m.message].length; i++){
        m.fadeBuffer.push({c: (Math.floor(Math.random()*12))+1, l: m.messages[m.message].charAt(i)});
      }
    }
    
    var do_cycles = false;
    var message = ''; 
    
    for(var i = 0; i < m.fadeBuffer.length; i++){
      var fader = m.fadeBuffer[i];
      if(fader.c > 0){
        do_cycles = true;
        fader.c--;
        message += m.codeletters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*m.codeletters.length));
      } else {
        message += fader.l;
      }
    }
    
    $(el).html(message);
    
    if(do_cycles === true){
      setTimeout(m.animateFadeBuffer, 20);
    } else {
      setTimeout(m.cycleText, 2000);
    }
  };
  
  m.cycleText = function(){
    m.message = m.message + 1;
    if(m.message >= m.messages.length){
      m.message = 0;
    }
    
    m.current_length = 0;
    m.fadeBuffer = false;
    $(el).html('');
    
    setTimeout(m.animateIn, 200);
  };
  
  m.init();
}

console.clear();
var messenger = new Messenger($('#messenger'));
```

I have looked up and down, to try and see where in the code I can do this. I also want to know what I need to add to be able to do this. I simply have no clue. I've seen other codes of similar where the codeletter area is colored, then the rest of the text another color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to color console output, you would use ANSI escape sequences that look something like this `\u001b[31;1m`, and which you can learn more about in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences). There is also an npm module available called [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) that greatly simplifies the process of implementing them.

If you're trying to color HTML output, you would just wrap each character in an individual `<span>` element and add a class or style attribute with CSS-styling for the desired color.

Comment: Thank you. Would either color console output or HTML output work with what I want to give color to?

Comment: Ok my mess up. Question should've been...where in my JS do I need to put the escape character codes?

Comment: Just so we're clear, where are you trying to display the colored text? In the console/terminal or in the browser?

Comment: on my browser, and on my blog. I have the CodePen if you'd like to see it? That's where I originally found it.

Comment: If that's the case, then you would not use color codes, but instead HTML, wrapping each character in a different `<span>`, as I had mentioned. You can do that on this line: `message += m.codeletters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*m.codeletters.length));` by changing it to `message += "<span style=\"color: red\">" + m.codeletters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*m.codeletters.length)) + "</span>";`

Comment: Thank you, this worked!. How bout for when it starts? It still shows white.

Comment: Found out where the scramble starts, the color to that is in the CSS