# What does [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m means on DotNetCore logs

Tags: c#, .net-core, ilogger

I have a DotNet Core application inside a Docker container and when I look into the logs produced by ILogger, I can see those characters:

```
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[1] 
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
```

Can you help me understand what they mean?

Comment: They're (remnants of) ANSI escape sequences i.e. [font formatting codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences)

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard. such a beginner question :S. Should I delete it as "duplicate"? Or do you prefer to write an answer? Thanks!

Comment: The behaviour of console coloring in `ConsoleLogger` can now be configured with more granularity in .NET 5.0. See this options class for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.simpleconsoleformatteroptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Oh, i wouldnt say it's a beginner question.. it's not so easy to google for/only easy if it's one of those things you "just know". I probably wouldn't have known if I hadn't owned a Commodore Amiga... 

Comment: Thank you @silkfire, I will take a look at Net 5 now. I am interested in figure out what is the right way of sending telemetry when running on AKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're (remnants of*) ANSI escape sequences i.e. font formatting codes - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences) goes into considerable detail as to the available options..

*the necessary initial escape character isn't presented in your post, either because it wasn't captured into the logs or whatever you viewed the logs with didn't show it/process it and the subsequent `[xxx` sequences as a formatting escape sequence