# How Do I Get Python to Output In RGB Color on a Windows Terminal?

Tags: python, windows, colors

I'm using a simple python (3.9.2) interpreter via command prompt on a windows 10 machine.

I am trying to get colored output texts from the python interpreter. I know how to get colored outputs however I'm looking for something that would allow RGB specified inputs so that I may output varying color intensities.

I found one thread [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) with such an example (you may have to scroll down to see the code line specifying the RGB input).

so.. I tried this part:
(I also had to import colorama for ANY of the escape sequences to display actual color)

```
from sty import fg, bg, ef, rs

foo = fg.red + 'This is red text!' + fg.rs
qui = fg(255, 10, 10) + 'This is red text using 24bit colors.' + fg.rs

# Add custom colors:

from sty import Style, RgbFg

fg.orange = Style(RgbFg(255, 150, 50))

buf = fg.orange + 'Yay, Im orange.' + fg.rs

print(foo, bar, baz, qux, qui, buf, sep='\n')
```

The `fg.red` worked okay, but the RGB specified lines did not produce the correct colors. nor the intensities. Is there anything else for suggestions where I can get this to work on a windows machine??

Comment: Is `colorama.init()` being called by chance? I discovered that even in the latest package version, calling this will break most extended color-support in Windows Terminal. `init()` is probably only designed to hook the console-output for older Windows support. Removing the `init()` call solved this same issue I was experiencing, with 24-bit rgb.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this as "Windows 10 Terminal" instead of "Command Prompt". The command prompt isn't able to output anything besides the 16 predefined colors at a time (foreground or background). There's an answer by SimpleBinary a few answers down from the one you were looking at that explains this limitation in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can find several good packages that solves your issue. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package for Python. [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) is lightweight, less verbose and supports RGB colors out of the box. Simply install the package with `pip install colorist` and type:

```py
from colorist import ColorRGB, BgColorRGB

dusty_pink = ColorRGB(194, 145, 164)
bg_steel_blue = BgColorRGB(70, 130, 180)

print(f"I want to use {dusty_pink}dusty pink{dusty_pink.OFF} and {bg_steel_blue}steel blue{bg_steel_blue.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of RGB color in terminal]

If you prefer to define colors in HSL, that's also possible as [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) will translate this to RGB:

```py
from colorist import ColorHSL, BgColorHSL

mustard_green = ColorHSL(60, 56, 43)
bg_steel_gray = BgColorHSL(190, 2, 49)

print(f"I want to use {mustard_green}mustard green{mustard_green.OFF} and {bg_steel_gray}steel blue{bg_steel_gray.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of HSL color in terminal]

Or similarly, you can also define colors in Hex:

```py
from colorist import ColorHex, BgColorHex

watermelon_red = ColorHex("#ff5733")
bg_mint_green = BgColorHex("#99ff99")

print(f"I want to use {watermelon_red}watermelon pink{watermelon_red.OFF} and {bg_mint_green}mint green{bg_mint_green.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of Hex color in terminal]

Note that not all terminals support advanced RGB colors as they weren't part of the initial [ANSI specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You may want to try various terminals to find the right one for you.

Comment: cANT INSTALL FOR 3.7

Comment: Colorist only supports Python 3.10 or higher, not version 3.7. It's already mentioned in the documentation: https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Many of the methods for fixing this problem require using third-party dependencies.
having less dependencies is a important factor if you have many clients dependant to your project.

I would recommend using [***ANSI escape codes***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) directly, they are very useful if you learn how to use them effectively without accessing abstractions ( third-party libraries for example ).

**colored_output.py**

```py
print("\33[31mHello, thanks for using this command\33[0m")
```

In this case, the output starts with the `\33[31m` ANSI escape code, in which the number `31m` refers to color red, after the output finishes, the `\33[0m` set the color back to default state, keep in mind that if you don't reset the color, the rest of the program outputs will be in the red color.

you can go one step further and add variable references to avoid verbosity in your strings.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Colors:
    red: str="\33[31m"
    default: str="\33[0m"


print(f"{Colors.red}this " +
 f"is a red colored text!{Colors.default}" +
 f"now were back to your default terminal color!"
)
```

The bonus points about the ANSI escape sequences is that beside from colors, they can be used for other types of cutomizations, the other point is that many terminals today support these defenitions. you can access the list of the sequences from the answers of [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences).

If you are producing an important piece of software to a known group of clients, I would recommend considering the envrionment that the clients are going to run your programs with, since terminals and environments may differ in the way they provide these codes ( although that is very not common since ANSI is the base standard for most systems, but is still quite possible ).

You can have a look at some of the differences mentioned [***here***](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548158/in-2019-is-it-safe-to-assume-that-all-terminals-understand-ansi-escape-codes)

At last, although these escape sequences provide a very good functionality, they are not easy to tackle with if you are looking for a fast-forward solution, as they take time to learn and master.

In this case a good solution would be using the [***colorist***](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/), which provide a API for working with effects and colors.