# VS Code BASH terminal - extra characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what I'm getting extra characters in VS Code BASH terminal window?

[VSCode BASH Terminal - extra characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmqvm.png)

Comment: I think those are ANSI Color codes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Found this just in case someone else could use it https://dev.to/neoelemento/styling-git-bash-3onh