# How can I separate colors in .zshrc?

Tags: terminal, zshrc

I'm trying to set the color of my git branch name and path in my terminal, but keep the rest of the text standard in the theme. The problem I have is that I was able to change the color of my git branch, but it also now changes the color of everything I'm typing in terminal to the same color as the git branch. I believe the problem is that in my prompt command the text isn't escaped correctly. How can I fix this?

```
# Find and set branch name var if in git repository.

function git_branch_name()
{
  branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}')
  if [[ $branch == "" ]];
  then
    :
  else
    echo '- ('$branch')'
  fi
}

# Enable substitution in the prompt.
setopt prompt_subst

COLOR_DIR=$'\e[1;32m'
COLOR_GIT=$'\e[38;5;39m'

# Config for prompt. PS1 synonym.
prompt='%2/ ${COLOR_GIT}$(git_branch_name) > ' (I believe the problem is here)
```

[image]

Comment: Set the color back to whatever the standard color is. That's a zsh thing, not a Git thing, so I snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Comment: So I changed it back to this "prompt='%2/ $(git_branch_name) > '"

Comment: That shows the git folder, but now it's white. I'm trying to customize my prompt, but it's not clear how to. I want the branch to be blue, the path to be green, and the text to be white.

Comment: I don't know what the zsh variables for these are, but in general, you print ESC [ <numbers with semicolons> m, and then after that, text shows up in colors, or other effects. Then you print ESC [ <more numbers> m, and after that, text shows up in different colors or other different effects. Repeat as desired. Set foreground and/or background to whatever you like each time. Use ESC [ m (with no numbers) to clear all settings.

Comment: Each of those `'\e[1;32m'` etc are the "make future characters be in particular colors" sequences. You can look up these ANSI color sequences: https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi+color+escape+codes (and see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4842424/1256452)).

Comment: How do I include this in my prompt so it's read correctly? This doesn't work prompt='%2/ $(COLOR_GIT)$(git_branch_name) > '

Comment: That's a zsh question, which I can't answer. In bash, there are no pre-defined color variables, so you have to set them yourself.