# What does \033[95m mean in Python?

Tags: python

I came across this line, and I have no idea what does it mean.

```
cor = ['\033[95m', '\033[96m', '\033[92m','\033[93m','\033[91m','\033[0m']
print(cor[3]+"\n[!]:"+cor[5]+"The ["+cor[4]+" Core"+cor[5]+" ]"+cor[3]+"Tool Folder Is Missing!!")
```

May I know the meaning of 95m, 96m, 92m, etc? Searching through SO, it looks like it's some kind of C operator, but where can I find the full list of these?

Comment: Does this answer help? [The ANSI escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/14277722)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are attribute codes to color or style the characters. Each one once set will cause all following text to be styled accordingly until changed or reset.