# How to do bold text using the ISO standard escape sequences?

Tags: c++, escaping, ansi-escape

I've created a namespace which would store ANSI values for logging purposes.

```cpp
namespace ANSI {
    static const char *BLACK_BG = "\x1B[48;2;0;0;0m";
    static const char *RED = "\x1B[38;2;255;0;0m";
    static const char *GREEN = "\x1B[38;2;0;255;0m";
    static const char *GREY = "\x1B[38;2;70;70;70m";
    static const char *EXIT = "\x1B[0m";
    static std::ostream &BOLD(std::ostream& log) { return log << "\e[1m"; }
}

// Example usage:
// std::cout << ANSI::BOLD << ANSI::GREEN << "This is bold green text" << ANSI::EXIT << "\n";
```

But when I try to compile using the `-pedantic` flag, it tells me that `\e[1m` is not an ISO standard escape sequence. It doesn't show the error if I remove the flag but I want to keep it at the same time.

P.S. If I'm doing something wrong with the code above, please let me know.

EDIT:
The bold escape sequence `\033[1m` works for my code.

Comment: What is `'\e'`?  That's not a valid escape sequence.  The other places in the code use `'\x1B'`, which is a valid escape sequence.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

Comment: To **bold**ly go where no text has gone... before.