# I want to write a document to be viewed via the 'less' command. Where can I find the formatting standards specifications?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, less, pandoc, file-format

I would like to convert Markdown files so these can be viewed via *[less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix))*...

However, I want the formatting (bold, italic, etc.) to be preserved and displayed accordingly... Unfortunately I cannot find the specifications.

---

My preferred approach would have been to use [Pandoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) to convert the md-files into a file type that *less* can properly display...

Comment: Styled/coloured text in a terminal window? Some keywords may be "[ANSI color escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)" and "[OSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences)" (Operating System Command) (very search unfriendly).

Comment: In general, formats like bold and italics don't exist on traditional text-based terminals. You usually have a palette of colours, and some limited effects like invert and blink, signalled by special control sequences. Less itself doesn't interpret these, but it can pass them through to the underlying terminal with the `-R` option.

Comment: What format exactly do you want to have it converted to?

Comment: Somewhat related: *[List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/)*. [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences/33206814#33206814) includes *"Font Effects ... Italic ... Not widely supported. Sometimes treated as inverse. ...   Bold or increased intensity"*. And *[How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/)*.

Comment: @IMSoP Less by default interprets backspaces (as if it is a hardcopy terminal). Character-backspace-underline has the effect of underlining the character. Character-backspace-character has the effect of bolding the character. This is how you see these effects in man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files of any format supported by pandoc can be read like Unix man pages:

```bash
pandoc --standalone --to=man INPUT_FILE | man -l -
```

This uses `less` by default, unless you have the `PAGER` variable set to some other value.

A good way to use it is to create a shell function:

```bash
mandoc () { pandoc --standalone --to=man "$@" | man -l - }
```

Now you can read files using Markdown, docx, LaTeX, etc. as if they were manpages.

```
mandoc README.md
mandoc term-project.tex
mandoc thesis.docx
# and so on
```

As you can see, the command causes pandoc to convert its input to a format called `man`, which is really groff man (see https://man.cx/groff_man(7)).

Comment: so many new things learned in one strike :) Thank you!