# Hex codes of Git standard colors

Tags: git, colors, git-diff

I have been searching for a while but I can't find it. What are the Hex codes of Git standard colors:
normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white and default?

Comment: I think git doesn't specify hex codes but uses the colors provided by your terminal.

Comment: black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white and bright <color> (eg, bright black (which looks grey), bright blue, bright cyan etc.). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors . Note that there are no hex colors for each color names as I can configure my terminal to render any color for "blue" and any color for "red". Indeed there are color themes like "Solarized", "Pastel", "High contrast" etc. that changes the hex values for the colors.

Comment: Here's an example of color themes for iTerm2 (a polular terminal on MacOS) https://iterm2colorschemes.com/. As you can see, the color "red" can be anything from peach to bright red to green (using a theme to simulate green monochrome displays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git uses [ANSI color escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences). Git maps the color names to escape codes in the file [`color.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/color.h).

The actual visible, rendered color depends on your terminal emulator and other contributing factors such as the configured color scheme.